# .htaccess determine if refferer is not current domain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-referer

I'm trying to create an .htaccess mod_rewrite that will behave differently if the current referer isn't my own domain. For instance, say I own example.com (i.e. www.example.com, http://example.com, etc). When somebody goes to example.com (or an subdomain such as beta.example.com), I want to ignore this .htaccess rule. So I guess the regex would basically just look for example.com somewhere in it and ignore those.

However, is a domain such as otherdomain.com (which is assumed to point to example.com via cname or A-record) access my site, I want to redirect them somewhere. Here's what I have so far that I believe is close but isn't working.

My main confusion with these rules is the part that comes after the RewriteRule (^$ in this case). I've seen a few different things put there in my Googling and I'm not sure on the differences. For instance, I've also seen just a ^, a (.*)$, etc.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://([^.]+\.)*(example)\.com
RewriteRule ^$ redirectfile.php [L]
```

I've also been messing with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(.+\.)*\.com
RewriteCond %1 !^(example)\.$
RewriteRule ^$ redirectfile.php [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://([^.]+\.)*example\.com 
RewriteRule ^ redirectfile.php [L]
```

You had `^$`, which would only match the home page.

I changed it to just `^` which will match every request, assuming that you want to match every request.

A `(.*)$` would also match every request, but also capture the match so that you reuse in in the target as $1

Comment: Thanks for those explanations. Those rules don't appear to be working, though. It's always redirecting regardless. I'm testing by going to it using random.example.com (this one should ignore the rule) and test.local (which points to the same server but should follow the rule). In each of these cases, I had it redirect to a PHP file that dumped the $_SERVER and HTTP_REFERER was empty, so I tried to use HTTP_HOST which had the right values. Still no luck on the rules, though. Is it because HTTP_HOST doesn't contain the http like that regex?

Comment: So my last statement must be it. I took out the http part and used HTTP_HOST, and it's working now. Is it safe to use HTTP_HOST? It's probably more reliable than HTTP_REFERER anyways, right?

Comment: @joshholat `HTTP_HOST` is more reliable, but it will always give you the domain of the page that you are requesting, not the domain of the page you came from. If you need the latter, then you should use `HTTP_REFERER`. Note that `HTTP_REFERER`  will be blank (empty string) if you type in the URL directly in the browser, have it bookmarked or came from a secure page.

Comment: Ahh, I was typing it in directly :-P Thanks, your responses were very helpful. HTTP_HOST should actually be what I need then. And I just modified the http part of your regex to get it to work.